# Name for a condition where one with their limited knowledge thinks of a problem as bigger than it really is?

Tags: terminology, bias

I know about Dunning-Kruger... where to put it bluntly, one overestimates oneself.

I am looking for a definition/name, to further research and reference in discussions with my peers, for a bias, that defines the following behavior:

- The person A has knowledge X in a field Y.
- The person estimates a problem in the field Y as being of complexity Z.
- Though, another person - B, in the field Y, having knowledge greater than X, sees Z as a much lesser problem or not a problem at all.

  - Implying that it's not worth solving, or that solution to a greater problem automatically solves the lesser one.

Of course, given that person B estimation is unbiased, therefore *objective*.

For example, I'm a software engineer with fair amount of experience and I can freely speculate (make educated guesses) about problems/solutions in fields outside of my immediate proficiency.

If, given the knowledge I have, I would estimate a problem in this outside field as generally/*objectively* BIG where people actually inside the field would not.

How is the condition called? (Assuming it's already defined)

This somehow might be related to Confirmation bias, but I do not commit to action, I abstain from it, because I see it as much too complex for me to tackle.

Answer (score 2):

I can't provide you with a direct term that you are looking for. However, I think the ***level of confidence*** comes close.

My reasoning is as follows: **Experience**/knowledge increases **task proficiency** [(Kuhlthau, 1999)](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/(SICI)1097-4571(1999)50:5%3C399::AID-ASI3%3E3.0.CO;2-L). Proficiency affects the level of **confidence**. Confidence, in turn, affects the perceived **task complexity** [(Chang, 2005)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S074756320400038X).

<sub>**References**

**-** [Kuhlthau, *JASIST* (1999); **50**(5): 399-412](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/(SICI)1097-4571(1999)50:5%3C399::AID-ASI3%3E3.0.CO;2-L)

**-** [Chang, *Computers Human Behav* (2005); **21**(5): 713-28](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S074756320400038X)</sub>